# Finding the maxium relative in array by using recursion

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

Cant find a solution to my assigment.

A number in an array is a relative maximum if its value is higher than its two neighbors. The maximum value is the sum of the differences between the number and its two neighbors. Write a program that asks for a user's array size (range between 10 and 100) and a user should insert the numbers (in the range between 1 and 1000) and call a **recursive function** that calculates the largest relative maximum that appears in the array, and prints it.
Example (in array size 15)
        24 28 22 4 6 7 8 6 5 11 **10 21 9** 4 13

23 should be printed because 21 (which appears in the three bold) is the largest relative maximum of 23 (21-10) + (21-9) = 23

What I did so far was to create what goes into the function but the recusive thinking is making it hard for me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int rMax(int arr[],int arrSize)
{

}

int main()
{
    int arr[100], size;
    // input check
    do {
        cout << "Please enter size of array:" << endl;
        cin >> size;
    } while (size <= 0);

    cout << "Please enter " << size << " numbers:" << endl;

    //input loop
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }



}
```

Comment: "which appears in the three underlined"... I can't see any underlines in the post

Comment: fixed to bold, ty

Comment: I don't see how recursion is useful for solving this task (best case runtime is `O(N)`, no divide and conquer here). My advice would be to first write the solution using a loop and then convert it to a recursive form to satisfy the assignment.

Comment: its homework, its for learning recursion @MaxLanghof

Comment: @Gil I know. That's exactly why first writing it in loop form and then transforming to the recursive form is probably the best approach. It will help you understand that (and how) the two approaches are equivalent and how you have to think about each one.

Comment: @Gil some problems are by nature recursive and some other not, to force the recursion when it is not natural for a given case is of course wrong. The recursion is a way to do , not a goal. If this can help you the most recursive solution I gave on S.O. is the [function _sum_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53998355/using-recursion-functions-only-to-calculate-the-final-sum-of-a-given-number/53998494#53998494)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is best when you can describe your problem in terms of a *similar, smaller* problem.

Lets take a rephrasing of the problem statement

> Find the element best satisfying *some property* in this array

and break it down into *smaller* sub problems

> Find the element satisfying *some property* in the first half of this array
>
> Find the element satisfying *some property* in the second half of this array

We then only need to consider 2 elements, and pick whichever is better. This splitting repeats by calling the function again, until we don't have anything left to halve, where we calculate the "*some property*"

A sketch

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int rMax(int * start, int * end)
{
    // Base case: we have only one element
    // We just calculate its "relative value"
    if (start == end)
        return (start[0] - start[-1]) + (start[0] - start[1]);

    // Recursive case: split into two halves and pick the best
    int * middle = start + ((end - start) / 2);

    int first = rMax(start, middle);
    int second = rMax(middle + 1, end);

    return std::max(first, second);        
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    // input check, need at least 3 elements to have any "relative maximum"
    do {
        std::cout << "Please enter size of array:" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> size;
    } while (size < 3);

    std::cout << "Please enter " << size << " numbers:" << std::endl;

    std::vector<int> arr(size);

    //input loop
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> arr[i];
    }

    // don't consider the first or last element, as they have only one adjacent value
    std::cout << rMax(arr.data() + 1, arr.data() + size - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion can be used here through a divide and conquer pattern. The key is to split the array in 2 pieces and find the relative maximum in each piece. When the size of the piece is 3, the answer is evident.

The key is that you must keep one element before the high part and one element after the low part. By the way it is enough to make sure that the minimum size of a part will be 3.

But you must also keep the (relative) index of the higher relative maximum in one piece *and* its value to be able to compare the relative maximum from both pieces, so I suggest you the following signature:

```
int rMax(int *arr, int size, int *index);   // returns the value of the relative max or 0
```

I let you write the actual implementation (after all **you** have to practice). Feel free to ask a new question if you are stuck in writing it.